# PHP Warning in for each

Tags: php, html, foreach, while-loop

So I'm having this problem:

I made an online quiz the answers are pushed into an array called answer.
It's working fine, but when I try to re-display the correct answer along with the answer that the user submitted im getting the invalid argument supplied foreach()

there is a while loop to get the correct answer from the database and the question.
I need to display for example the following:

Question 1: --------
Correct Answer: A. XXX
Your Answer: $answer[0]

Question 2: --------
Correct Asnwer: C. XXX
Your Answer: $answer[1]

```
<?php

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");

        if(!$con) {
            die('Could Not Connect: '.mysqli_error($con));
        }

        mysqli_select_db($con,"rankone");

        $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM rankone_quizzes WHERE (Bundle='Free-Exam-A') ORDER BY ID ASC");

        echo '<ol>';

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {


         foreach ($answer as $answer) {

            echo'<li> <h3> '.($row["Question"]).'</h3>';

            if (($row["CorrectAnswer"]) == "A"){

                echo'<p>A. '.($row["Option1"]).'</p>';
                echo'<p>You Answer: $answer</p>';

            }elseif(($row["CorrectAnswer"]) == "B") {

                echo'<p>B. '.($row["Option2"]).'</p>';
                echo'<p>You Answer: $answer</p>';

            }elseif(($row["CorrectAnswer"]) == "C") {

                echo'<p>C. '.($row["Option3"]).'</p>';
                echo'<p>You Answer: $answer</p>';
            }

            echo'</li>';
            echo'<br><br>';
            }
            echo'</ol>';

            ?>
```

Comment: For a start, post your code here, not as image.

Comment: Oh ok sorry, here you go i added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the
`foreach ($answer as $answer) {`

By giving the `loop value` the same name as the `$answer` array you override the `answer` array with the first element value.

Try giving your array with answers a different name as the iteration value.
E.g.:

```
// defining your answers
$answers = [...];


foreach ($answers as $answer) {
```